# Target of URI doesn't exist: '../images/'. Try creating the file referenced by the URI, or Try using a URI for a file that does

Tags: flutter, dart, import

[image]

## I am creating a user interface for a messenger app. and I'm having trouble importing photos for my chat list

```
'import '../models/chatUsersModel.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../widgets/conversationList.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:app_chat/images/userImage1.jpeg';
import '../images/';
```

> import images resolve error

```
class ChatPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ChatPage({super.key});

  @override
  _ChatPageState createState() => _ChatPageState();
}

class _ChatPageState extends State<ChatPage> {
  List<ChatUsers> chatUsers = [
    ChatUsers(
        name: "Andrey Jones",
        messageText: "Can you please share the file?",
*this image not displayed[![enter image description here][1]][1]*        imageURL: "../images/userImage7.jpeg",
        time: "24 Feb"),
    ChatUsers(
        name: "John Wick",
        messageText: "How are you?",
```

> did i define the images correctly?

```
imageURL: "assets/images/userImage8.jpeg",
        time: "18 Feb"),
    ChatUsers(
        time: "Now",
        imageURL: 'images/userImage1.jpeg',
        messageText: 'Awesome Setup',
        name: 'Jane Russel'),
    ChatUsers(
        time: "Yesterday",
        imageURL: 'images/userImage2.jpeg',
        messageText: "That's Great",
        name: "Glady's Murphy"),
    ChatUsers(
        name: "Jorge Henry",
        messageText: "Hey where are you?",
        imageURL: "images/userImage3.jpeg",
        time: "31 Mar"),
    ChatUsers(
        name: "Philip Fox",
        messageText: "Busy! Call me in 20 mins",
        imageURL: "images/userImage4.jpeg",
        time: "28 Mar"),
    ChatUsers(
        name: "Debra Hawkins",
        messageText: "Thankyou, It's awesome",
        imageURL: "images/userImage5.jpeg",
        time: "23 Mar"),
    ChatUsers(
        name: "Jacob Pena",
        messageText: "will update you in evening",
        imageURL: "images/userImage6.jpeg",
        time: "17 Mar"),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            SafeArea(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16, top: 10),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    const Text(
                      "Conversations",
                      style:
                          TextStyle(fontSize: 32, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          left: 8, right: 8, top: 2, bottom: 2),
                      height: 30,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                        color: Colors.pink[50],
                      ),
                      child: Row(
                        children: const <Widget>[
                          Icon(
                            Icons.add,
                            color: Colors.pink,
                            size: 20,
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 2,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            'Voila',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 32, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),

            //Поисковая панель
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16, left: 16, right: 16),
              child: TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: "Search...",
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey.shade600),
                  prefixIcon: Icon(
                    Icons.search,
                    color: Colors.grey.shade600,
                    size: 20,
                  ),
                  filled: true,
                  fillColor: Colors.grey.shade100,
                  contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey.shade100)),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            ListView.builder(
              itemCount: chatUsers.length,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
              physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ConversationList(
                  name: chatUsers[index].name,
                  messageText: chatUsers[index].messageText,
                  imageUrl: chatUsers[index].imageURL,
                  time: chatUsers[index].time,
                  isMessageRead: (index == 0 || index == 3) ? true : false,
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}'
```

all the code works without errors, but something is wrong with loading images, has anyone come across this or maybe knows what's wrong?

Comment: `import` is for importing Dart code.  You can't use it with an image file or with a directory.  If you're trying to include images with your Flutter application, you should [add them as assets](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/assets-and-images).

Answer (score 0):

You used the image the wrong way
in the `dart` language, the images imported like this:

```
import 'package:app_chat/images/userImage1.jpeg';
```

**is wrong**

you should use `import` just when you want to get a dependency to use it inside your file.

to use images in your flutter application, you need to declare the source assets folders/files in the `pubspect.yaml`, please refer to this. [Adding assets and images](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/assets-and-images)

**Solution**:

- remove the image imports in your files.
- make sure you declare the assets folder/files in `pubspec.yaml`.
- run `flutter pub get`
- use the images from that folder with its path as a string.

example:

```
Image.asset("assets/image1.jpeg");
```